# Multiple 3D sounds in Three.js

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js

I'm a bit struggling on this one.

I want to do a line made of cubes, each one has a sound and if you get closer to it you can hear its sound.

The goal is to navigate from the beginning of the line to the end, this way you are able to play the different sounds and make a 'music'.

The problem I have is that I can only hear 6 of the 20 cubes.

Here is the online example : http://maximebonhomme.fr/mission87/tests

(Left click to move forward, Right click to move backward)

--

This is the function to create the sound :
(from : http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_sound)

```
var Sound = function ( sources, radius, volume ) {
  var audio = document.createElement( 'audio' );
  for ( var i = 0; i < sources.length; i ++ ) {
    var source = document.createElement( 'source' );
    source.src = sources[ i ];
    audio.appendChild( source );
  }
  this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
  this.play = function () {
    audio.play();
  }
  this.update = function ( camera ) {
    var distance = this.position.distanceTo( camera.position );
    if ( distance <= radius ) {
      audio.volume = volume * ( 1 - distance / radius );
      // console.log(distance/radius/2);
      material_sky.color.setHSL(distance / radius / 2 ,0.666,0.666);
    } else {
      audio.volume = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

--

This is where I create my cubes

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++){
  array[i] = new THREE.Mesh(music_geo,material_draw);
  array[i].position.z = i*20;
  array[i].position.x = 30;
  scene.add(array[i]);

  sounds[i] = new Sound( [ soundSRC+source2+'.mp3', soundSRC+source2+'.ogg' ], 10, 1 );
  sounds[i].position.copy( array[i].position );
  sounds[i].play();
}
```

--

And this is where I update the sounds with the camera 
(in my render function)

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++){
  sounds[i].update( camera );
}
```

--

So I would like to know if it is me doing something wrong or if it's Three.js, the browser or something that can't support more than 6 sounds.

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT 08/06/14**

I managed to get over this issue by using the Web Audio API
Here's the fix if someone is interested, the sound is a frequency (that's what I wanted) but it'll work with a song file I suppose.

The function that creates the sound :

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty('AudioContext') && !window.hasOwnProperty('webkitAudioContext'))
    window.webkitAudioContext = AudioContext;

var context = new webkitAudioContext();

var Sound = function ( radius, volume ) {

  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  var osc = context.createOscillator();
  var oscGain =context.createGainNode();
  osc.type = 0;

  osc.connect(oscGain);
  oscGain.connect(context.destination);
  osc.noteOn(0); 
  osc.frequency.value = 500;
  oscGain.gain.value = 0;

  this.position = new THREE.Vector3();

  this.update = function ( camera ) {
    var distance = this.position.distanceTo( camera.position );
    if ( distance <= radius ) {
      oscGain.gain.value = volume * ( 1 - distance / radius );

      material_sky.color.setHSL(distance / radius / 2 ,0.666,0.666);
    } else {
      oscGain.gain.value = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: When I open that page my browser starts to download 20 mp3 files of 7MB each.  For me at least it takes a LONG time for those downloads to finish.  Perhaps you are only hearing the ones that have finished downloading.

Comment: @James Yeah this is definitely not a good approach since some browser will play 6 sounds, some others will play 14 sounds and as you said it's loading 20 times the same file ... 
I think I'm going to look into the Web Audio API.

Thanks for the reply

Comment: You should definitely post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get over this issue by using the Web Audio API
Here's the fix if someone is interested, the sound is a frequency (that's what I wanted) but it'll work with a song file I suppose.

The function that creates the sound :

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty('AudioContext') && !window.hasOwnProperty('webkitAudioContext'))
    window.webkitAudioContext = AudioContext;

var context = new webkitAudioContext();

var Sound = function ( radius, volume ) {

  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  var osc = context.createOscillator();
  var oscGain =context.createGainNode();
  osc.type = 0;

  osc.connect(oscGain);
  oscGain.connect(context.destination);
  osc.noteOn(0); 
  osc.frequency.value = 500;
  oscGain.gain.value = 0;

  this.position = new THREE.Vector3();

  this.update = function ( camera ) {
    var distance = this.position.distanceTo( camera.position );
    if ( distance <= radius ) {
      oscGain.gain.value = volume * ( 1 - distance / radius );

      material_sky.color.setHSL(distance / radius / 2 ,0.666,0.666);
    } else {
      oscGain.gain.value = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: Wy don't you use THREE-js's PositionalAudio?

Comment: @JoeriBultheel this question is from 2014